# Switch case program

Tags: switch-statement, case

This is a Swtich Case program. I am not sure why this happens in this program. Can anyone explain why this happening?

```
class SwitchCase{
     public static void main(String args[]){
         switch(3*4+2){
            case 12:
                System.out.println("Hello");
            case 14:
                System.out.println("Hello World");

            case 16:
                System.out.println("Hello World Aqib");
            case 18:
                System.out.println("Hello World Mohd");
            default:
                System.out.println("Hahah....");
            }
        }
  } 

 Output:
     Hello World 
     Hello World Aqib
     Hello World Mohd
     Hahah....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After each case you need a break;

```
 case 12:
                System.out.println("Hello");
                break;
.....
```

Comment: Thank you very much